# How to add left side margin on leftview of uitextfield in ios?

Tags: ios, textfield

i have to set the frame of image that i have assigned to leftview.
see my code.

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];

imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0 ,15, userNameTextField.frame.size.height);

userNameTextField.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
userNameTextField.leftView = imageView;
```

Answer (score -1):

Margins are implemented in the iOS UIKit as content insets. The following code will result in a 5 pixel margin on the left of the text view

`[atextView  setTextContainerInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 5, 0, 0)];`